# Sorting an array from DB based on Google API distance (usort)

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-maps

I get the address and the name from the database and I want to sort the results based on the distance that is being calculated by Google Maps API after it gets the destination from a query. It currently displays the following error messages 4 times (repeating them):

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'routes' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app2\test.php on line 36

Warning: Illegal string offset 'legs' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app2\test.php on line 36

Warning: Illegal string offset 'distance' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app2\test.php on line 36

Warning: Illegal string offset 'text' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app2\test.php on line 36
```

The printed array is displayed after the errors and it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 0.3 km [1] => 1.7 km )
```

I want the result to be Name `($row['name'])` and number of kms, all sorted in an ascending order based on kms. How should my usort look in order to achieve this? Or is there a problem somewhere else?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/session.php';
require_once 'includes/config.php';
require_once 'includes/design_query.php';
include_once 'includes/header.php';
include_once 'includes/menu.php';

//$origin = $_COOKIE['origin'];
//$id=$_GET['id'];

$origin = "Bucuresti+Avrig+30";
$id = 3;
$query = ("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE category_id='$id'");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$address = $row['Judet'] . '+' . $row['Localitate'] . '+' . $row['Strada'] . '+' . $row['Numar'];
$address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);

$fullurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' . $origin . '&destination=' . $address .  '&alternatives=true&sensor=true';
$json_a = json_decode((file_get_contents($fullurl)),true); 

asort($row);

//echo $row['name'];
//echo "<span class='badge'>" . $json_a['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text'] . "</span></button>";

$whole_data[] = $json_a['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text'];
}

 function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text'] == $b['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text'] < $b['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    $a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

    usort($whole_data, "cmp");

    print_r($whole_data);

include_once 'includes/footer.php';
include_once 'includes/scripts.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all let me just say that this code is a mess! Seeing the commented line where id is obtained from GET also makes it pretty clear that it will be prone to sql injection.

Anyway here is an attempt to make it do what you want (just important parts):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$address = $row['Judet'] . '+' . $row['Localitate'] . '+' . $row['Strada'] . '+' . $row['Numar'];
$address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);

$fullurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' . $origin . '&destination=' . $address .  '&alternatives=true&sensor=true';
$json_a = json_decode((file_get_contents($fullurl)),true); 



$whole_data[] = array("name" => $row["name"], "value" => $json_a['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['value'],  "text" => $json_a['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']);
}

 function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a['value'] == $b['value']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['value'] < $b['value']) ? -1 : 1;
    }


    usort($whole_data, "cmp");
// example print
foreach($whole_data as $row){
    echo "$row[name] $row[text] <br/>";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is a mess. It will be integrated in a phone application so the user won't load the page himself in a browser. It also uses MySQL instead of MySQLi or PDO. After modifying my code as you suggested the output is: Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Hotel Artemis [value] => 314 [text] => 0.3 km ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Hotel Marriott [value] => 1703 [text] => 1.7 km ) )  How can I sort it now? I guess I need to use foreach?

Comment: it's already sorted ASC by distance value. This is done by usort call.

Comment: btw: even if it's not usually used in browser a malicious request can still be sent the same way your phone app will send normal requests. And you never know, better safe than sorry.

Comment: That is true! :) Weird thing is I got the array sorted out and I still can't take the data that I want from the array. It's been a while since I practiced with PHP. I tried an example on the internet and replaced the array name with my own, doesn't seem to work. Echoes some Undefined offset errors. This is the script that I used: for ($row = 0; $row <  4; $row++) {
   echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
   echo "<ul>";
   for ($col = 0; $col <  3; $col++) {
     echo "<li>".$whole_data[$row][$col]."</li>";
   }
   echo "</ul>";
} Any idea?

Comment: Thats because you're using number indices whereas the whole_data array has string indices, you want to use indices like "name", "text" and "value".

Comment: Can you please edit your post to contain an example? I'm looking at different array examples on Code Academy and w3schools but can't seem to get the grasp, I always get either an undefined index or a notice that i'm trying to convert an array to a string.

Comment: You wanna do something like `$whole_data[0]["name"]` to print name column from 1st row. Similary for the text and value columns. If you need other columns from either the mysql row or json just add the to whole_data array in the while loop. This is basic stuff we're talking about here, you should first try to learn this BEFORE building any kind of a bigger app.

Comment: $zero=0;
echo $whole_data[$zero]["name"];
echo "</br>";
echo $whole_data[$zero]["text"];
echo "</br>";
$zero++; Added this in the while loop but now usort became useless as they're not ordered as they should

Comment: I added an example print as I suspect you put your print somewhere before the usort call. This really is too much of a discussion for comments. I suggest you try to fiddle around with it yourself and figure out what it actually does. This question is about sorting, if you have a problem with something else you should find out whether something like that has already been asked before and if not ask it yourself in new question.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! How is this kind of array called? I want to look into them. :)

Comment: They are called associative arrays. Check [PHP documentation on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)